# Para que serve o encoding em Base64?

Tags: base64

Praticamente toda linguagem de programação que se preze tem sua implementação de *encoding* e *decoding* de uma cadeia de caracteres para uma cadeia em caracteres em Base64.

Mas para que serve o Base64 propriamente dito?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Base64 é um método para [codificação](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codifica%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_caracteres) de dados para transferência na Internet (codificação MIME para transferência de conteúdo) . É utilizado frequentemente para transmitir dados binários por meios de transmissão que lidam apenas com texto, como por exemplo para enviar arquivos anexos por email.

É constituído por 64 caracteres ([A-Za-z0-9], "/" e "+") que deram origem ao seu nome. O carácter "=" é utilizado como um sufixo especial e a especificação original (RFC 989) definiu que o símbolo "*" pode ser utilizado para delimitar dados convertidos, mas não criptografados, dentro de um stream.

Exemplo de codificação:

```
Texto original: hello world
Texto convertido para Base64: aGVsbG8gd29ybGQK
```

A codificação Base64 é frequentemente utilizada quando existe uma necessidade de transferência e armazenamento de dados binários para um dispositivo designado para trabalhar com dados textuais. Esta codificação é amplamente utilizada por aplicações em conjunto com a linguagem de marcação XML, possibilitando o armazenamento de dados binários em forma de texto.

[Fonte](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)

Answer (score 14):

Algumas vezes você quer transferir alguns dados em binário e você não pode fazer essa transferência porque alguns meios de comunicação são feitos para streamer de texto.

Como exemplo você tem a seguinte representação de dados em um array:

```
nome = "Joao"
idade = 20
```

Você pode fazer essa transferência de dados utilizando a forma texto desses dados, como por exemplo em `JSON`

```
{"nome":"joao", "idade":20}
```

Nos casos dos dados `binários` você não pode simplesmente pegar o valor propriamente dito deles e fazer essa representação de texto, ai entra o `Base64`.

Para contornar essa situação as pessoas codificam seus dados binários em Base64 para poderem fazer essa representação de texto para qualquer tipo de transferência e uso.

Existem diversos outros codificadores que possam ser utilizados, mas o mais comum é o Base64

Answer (score 12):

O conjunto de caracteres US-ASCII possui 95 caracteres "imprimíveis", além de outros 33 caracteres de controle (0 a 31 e 127, ou 00-1F e 7F em hexadecimal), originalmente usados para controlar dispositivos tal como impressoras, etc. Sendo a codificação mais "universal" existente (praticamente todas as outras, incluindo Unicode ou os "*code pages"* do Windows, são superconjuntos desta), um texto em ASCII enviado de uma origem provavelmente será bem aceito em qualquer destino (e intermediários) sem que haja corrupção de dados. Quando um dado (texto ou binário) não pode ser expresso em ASCII sem modificações, às vezes é desejável codificá-lo em um texto ASCII antes do seu envio, decodificando-o novamente ao chegar no seu destino.

A maior potência de 2 menor que 95 é 64. A princípio *poderia-se* tentar codificar dados na base 95 mesmo, mas isso é complicado e por muitas vezes ineficiente. A vantagem da base 64 é que cada 3 bytes (3*8 = 24 bits) da entrada resultam em exatamente 4 caracteres da saída (4*6 = 24 bits), de modo que pode-se fazer a conversão de e para binário com um uso constante de memória e operações bastante simples.

A codificação base64 usa todas as letras maiúsculas e minúsculas e todos os dígitos, no total de 62 caracteres, mais dois outros escolhidos caso a caso, porém tradicionalmente sendo o `+` e a `/`. O `=` também é muito usado para delimitar o fim dos dados (quando seu tamanho não é múltiplo de 3), sendo comum ver um (`=`) ou dois (`==`) desse símbolo no final de strings em base64. Uma alternativa menos comum - quando não se quer usar nada além de letras e números, nem fazer distinção entre maiúsculas e minúsculas - é a base 32, que usa todas as letras mais os números de 0 a 5.