# Qual o formato a imagem é convertida ao ser solicitada pelo navegador?

Tags: navegador-de-internet

Isso é mais uma curiosidade, dei uma rápida pesquisada e não encontrei algo que explicasse como isso funciona.

Na prática quando desenvolvemos, temos alguns métodos para solicitar uma imagem ao servidor e exibir na tela do browser no cliente. Um jeito dependendo do caso pode ser bom usar, que é deixar a imagem convertida na base64, tem pessoas que não gostam assim, eu acredito que dessa forma é bom pra se utilizar imagens pequenas, diminuindo a quantidade de arquivos nos diretorios. O google imagens funciona dessa forma, emoticons do whats app versao web tambem funciona assim.

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7"></img>
```

A outra maneira, a mais tradicional é preencher o `src` com o caminho da localidade da imagem. E ai surge a curiosidade, qual o método  utilizado pelo servidor para converter a imagem para enviar-la ao cliente (navegador/browser)?
exemplo:

`<img src="img/imagem.png"></img>`

Comment: A princípio, não há conversão alguma - ou a imagem existe no servidor com o nome requisitado, ou não existe; e independentemente do nome, o servidor pode especificar o formato no *mime type* e/ou o *browser* pode inspecionar a imagem para descobrir seu conteúdo (não sei exatamente o que acontece quando o *mime type* não corresponde ao formato do arquivo). A propósito, o base64 [aumenta em 33% o tamanho dos dados](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/53107/215), não sendo uma boa opção para arquivos grandes, mas como você apontou de fato para arquivos pequenos economiza um *round-trip* ao servidor.

Comment: acho que ele quis usar algum outro termo ao invés da palavra "converter".. essa palavra muda todo o sentido da questão...

Comment: comentando um pouco mais, parte da descrição da pergunta já responde a própria pergunta.. rsrsr.. esse esquema aplicando data:image é mais para imagens pequenas. Imagine 50 imagens pequenas numa única página. São 50 requisições ao servidor.. Num serviço de alto tráfego, isso se converte num custo significativo $$.

Comment: Hum sim, então cada imagem tem uma requisição nova ao servidor. A minha duvida é só como o servidor envia a imagem na solicitação normal como dado no exemplo, é em array de bytes? ou algum outro tipo de dados ? é mais uma curiosidade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nenhum tipo de conversão ocorre: a imagem é simplesmente serializadas em um array de bytes e este é enviado no corpo da resposta HTTP.