# Como fazer uma solicitação POST no console do navegador?

Tags: javascript, javascript-eventos

Boa noite pessoal!
Estou estudando testes de penetração em um site de estudos voltado para ataques.
Pra eu poder me cadastrar eu tenho que "invadir" a página de cadastro.
Basicamente eu tenho que digitar uma função no console do navegador e ele gera automaticamente o código.

O código é esse:

```js
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('1 i(4){h 8={"4":4};$.9({a:"7",5:"6",g:8,b:\'/d/e/n\',c:1(0){3.2(0)},f:1(0){3.2(0)}})}1 j(){$.9({a:"7",5:"6",b:\'/d/e/k/l/m\',c:1(0){3.2(0)},f:1(0){3.2(0)}})}',24,24,'response|function|log|console|code|dataType|json|POST|formData|ajax|type|url|success|api|invite|error|data|var|verifyInviteCode|makeInviteCode|how|to|generate|verify'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Eu digito no console  makeInviteCode();
e ele me retorna uma string encriptada em base64 que decriptada informa a seguinte mensagem:

> Para gerar o código de convite, faça uma solicitação POST para /api/invite/generate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos analisar o código primeiramente.

Quando acessamos a `URL` responsável por criar essas funções, obtemos o seguinte código:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return c.toString(36)};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[c.toString(a)]=k[c]||c.toString(a)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('1 i(4){h 8={"4":4};$.9({a:"7",5:"6",g:8,b:\'/d/e/n\',c:1(0){3.2(0)},f:1(0){3.2(0)}})}1 j(){$.9({a:"7",5:"6",b:\'/d/e/k/l/m\',c:1(0){3.2(0)},f:1(0){3.2(0)}})}',24,24,'response|function|log|console|code|dataType|json|POST|formData|ajax|type|url|success|api|invite|error|data|var|verifyInviteCode|makeInviteCode|how|to|generate|verify'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

Esse código é responsável por criar as funções abaixo:

```
function verifyInviteCode(code) {
    var formData = {
        "code": code
    };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formData,
        url: '/api/invite/verify',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
}
function makeInviteCode() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: '/api/invite/how/to/generate',
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        },
        error: function(response) {
            console.log(response)
        }
    })
}
```

Agora que sabemos que as funções para geração e validação dos tokens, vamos chamar a função para geração, para isso basta executar o código abaixo no console do navegador:

```
makeInviteCode()
```

Essa função retornará um objeto. Esse objeto contém:

- `status` de retorno
- O `token` "criptografado"
- E o `enctype` que é a forma que ele foi "criptografado"

Esses valores são aleatórios, por isso você pode receber o valor "criptografado" em `base64`, `rot13` etc.

**Valores retornados**

Quando testei, recebi um [rot13](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) e um [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64).

O `base64¹` é um método para codificação de dados para transferência na Internet (codificação MIME para transferência de conteúdo)

Já o `rot13` é a rotação 13 vezes de uma determinada letra do alfabeto, por exemplo, se pegarmos a letra `a` e rotacionarmos 13 vezes, o valor será de `n`.

Para transformar esses valores, você pode utilizar sites como:

http://www.rot13.com/
https://www.base64decode.org/

**Enviando requisição do tipo POST**

Agora que sabemos que fazer, vamos capturar nosso convite. Para isso é necessário enviar uma requisição do tipo *POST* para a URL indicada no passo acima.

Para isso iremos utilizar o `XMLHttpRequest`, por exemplo:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onload = function( e ){ console.log(e.target.response) }
xhr.open("POST", "/api/invite/generate")
xhr.send();
```

Pronto! Já conseguimos nosso código. Agora é só decodificarmos o código em `base64` e você já pode se cadastrar no site.

> *Obs.:* Apesar de ajudar a conseguir isso, o justo é que você sempre e sempre procure na internet. A "graça" estar em descobrir.

---

<sup>Referências:</sup>
<sup>¹ [Para que serve o encoding em Base64?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53102/para-que-serve-o-encoding-em-base64)</sup>

Comment: Valdeir, muito obrigado pela resposta!

Comment: Mas eu consegui resolver esse enigma! Eu usei uma requisição em ajax. Quando eu fui requisitar o código ele me deu o código em base64, e decodifiquei, consegui o serial de convite. Apesar da sua bela resposta e explicação, eu consegui por mim mesmo achar a resposta.. Fiquei muito feliz por conseguir sozinho.. Mas mesmo assim, muito obrigado!

Comment: @SandsonCosta que bom que conseguiu antes da resposta. Segue uma dica de site para estudos: https://security.stackexchange.com Bons estudos!