# Melhor forma de armazenar imagens?

Tags: aplicação-web, imagem, armazenamento

Qual a melhor forma de se armazenar imagens?

- Em um diretório especial, por exemplo: `public/images`;
- Em `base64`, em uma base de dado;
- Outra forma (a qual não citei anteriormente).

E por quê?

*Nota: Estou utilizando uma base de dados MongoDB.*

Comment: Isso depende de qual vai ser o banco utilizado, em `NoSQL` 
o firebase oferece o storage o MongoDB oferece o GridFS, em `SQL` também pode variar de acordo com o banco escolhido

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta.

Comment: Relacionadas: [Para que serve o encoding em Base64?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53102/para-que-serve-o-encoding-em-base64); [Gravar imagem base64 no banco ou fazer upload](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/152457/gravar-imagem-base64-no-banco-ou-fazer-upload); [Salvar no banco de dados o conteúdo binário de uma imagem](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/42886/salvar-no-banco-de-dados-o-conteúdo-binário-de-uma-imagem/60296#comment222007_60296)

Comment: Pesquise sobre "Image CDN" pode ser que te interesse dependendo do seu projeto. E lembre que o Base64 não fica em cash, sempre vai ser uma nova requisição, e para imagens menores que 5kb não costuma valer a pena