# Criptografia BASE64

Tags: criptografia, base64

Estou concluindo um trabalho da faculdade, e gostaria de saber um tópico que não achei em português na internet.

Quais os benefícios da **base64**?

Comment: Um dos benefícios é retirar espaços e caracteres especiais, evitando conflito em outras partes da aplicação em que esses caracteres podem ter um significado especial

Comment: Veja se não é isso que você procura  Aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/53102/para-que-serve-o-encoding-em-base64

Comment: Base64 é uma maneira de representar dados binários em string, assim como a representação hexadecimal também é. Mas como o Guilherme citou os caracteres são escolhidos para minimizar qualquer problema com encoding possível.

Comment: Só lembrando que Base 64 **não** é criptografia: https://www.di-mgt.com.au/encode_encrypt.html

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, o Base64 não é uma criptografia, mas sim uma codificação qualquer. Ele não tem o intuito de proteger a informação, muito menos tornar ela irrecuperável ou criar uma outra informação indistinguível de algo aleatório.

---

A "vantagem" do Base64 é apenas possibilitar a transmissão dados binários usando caracteres ASCII.

Por exemplo, uma chave pública, criptográfica, é bastante próxima do aleatório, o que indica que uma chave poderia ser `[]byte{0x06, 0xFA, 0x14...}`, se você simplesmente fosse mostrar esta chave, em ASCII, ela se tornaria:

```
ú
```

Entretanto em HEX ficaria `06FA14` e em Base64 ficaria `BvoU`. A mesma informação está apenas representada de outra maneira. Os certificados de TLS, o OpenPGP, (...) podem ser codificados em Base64, justamente para permitir a copia mais facilmente. Mas, note que você não deve usar as funções padrões de decodificação, já que a maior parte usa table-lookup. O BoringSSL e o LibSodium, por exemplo, decodificam os certificados em *tempo-constante* e evitam o table-lookup. Lembre-se, novamente, que o Base64 não tem o intuito de proteger a informação, pelo contrário, ainda pode tornar mais inseguro nestes casos obscuros.

---

Um outro bom exemplo é os links, já notou que no YouTube, no Instagram e em vários lugares, possui um link como `?id=ABCDEFER`, e que tem sempre um tamanho fixo? Normalmente ele é um Base64, ou extremamente similar (não agrupando por 3 bytes).

A vantagem neste caso é: o cliente recebe sempre um `id` de tamanho fixo (11 caracteres, já que uint64 tem 8 bytes) e o servidor armazena só 8 bytes. Se o `id` fosse numérico, o cliente poderia ter um `?id=18014398509481984` (17 bytes).

E falando em links, já notou que quando quer incorporar uma imagem direto num HTML você usa `<img src="data:image/png;base64, AAAA....>`. Isso é feito justamente porque o `png` é um dado binario, usar o Base64 faz com que a informação representadas apenas em caracteres  específicos. Dessa forma, se a imagem original tivesse um mero `[]byte{..., 0x22, ...}`, ele seria representado como `"` em ASCII, o que iria quebrar a tag do HTML. Mas, com o Base64 o mesmo `0x22` será representado de outra forma.