# Posso usar uma combinação de algoritmos diferentes para gerar o hash de uma senha?

Tags: php, criptografia, md5, sha1

Estou com uma dúvida aqui, fiz uns testes no servidor local, e queria saber se alguém já fez algo parecido, e se o banco de dados suporta tantos caracteres assim.

A ideia de mesclar vários tipos de criptografias, é aumentar o nível de segurança do site, caso seja possível usar dessa maneira.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Gerador de senhas</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- o objetivo desse estudo é fazer um script de senhas criptografadas com autenticação-->
      <?php
        $a = 'umasenhaBemforteparaserqueBrada135';//senha do usuario

        //esse foi outro teste, só que deixa com muitos caracteres ->$cripto = md5($string).sha1($string).md5($string).base64_encode($string).sha1($string).base64_encode($string);
        $senhacodificada = sha1(md5($a).sha1(md5($a)).md5(sha1($a).base64_encode($a)).base64_encode($a)).md5(base64_encode($a).sha1(md5($a).base64_encode(sha1($a)))).base64_encode(sha1(md5($a)));
        //echo $senhacodificada;


        if(isset($_POST['acao'])){
          if($_POST['senha'] !='' ){
            $c = $_POST['senha'];
              $compara =   sha1(md5($c).sha1(md5($c)).md5(sha1($c).base64_encode($c)).base64_encode($c)).md5(base64_encode($c).sha1(md5($c).base64_encode(sha1($c)))).base64_encode(sha1(md5($c)));
              if($compara == $senhacodificada){
              echo '<br>';
              echo 'senha igual';
              echo '<hr>';
              echo $compara;
            }else{
              echo '<hr>';
              echo 'a senha é diferente';
            }
          }else{
            echo 'campos vazios nao sao permitidos';
          }
        }
       ?>

       <form method="post">
         <input type="text" name="senha">
         <input type="submit" name="acao" value="logar">    
       </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Leandro ninguém leva downvote,por causa de sinalização de  duplicada.

Comment: Recomendo realizar a contagem dos caracteres e confirmar se a quantidade está dentro dos limites de campos VARCHAR, TEXT ou SMALLTEXT no sql. Vale lembrar que tamanho de senha não garante segurança uma vez que seu código pode estar falho e permitir INJECTIONS. Mas enfim, isso é contigo já! boa sorte!

Comment: Opa, blz, vou contar os caracteres e conferir os limites. Sql to com script protegido e com verificações em todas url do site, a dúvida era mesmo saber se esse método de criptografia é usado. Obrigado

Answer (score 3):

<sup>*A `$senhacodificada` que você gerou terá sempre 128 caracteres, que é um tamanho que qualquer banco de dados moderno vai suportar sem problemas. Na verdade o limite dos principais bancos de dados é bem maior que isso, e o único problema será se o campo for definido com um tamanho menor (por exemplo, a coluna foi criada como `VARCHAR(100)`, aí não vai caber 128 caracteres mesmo). Mas o principal problema aqui é outro...*</sup>

---

## [Não invente sua própria criptografia](https://security.meta.stackexchange.com/a/915)

Fazer uma combinação maluca de hashes, apesar de parecer uma boa ideia, não é, e não faz a menor diferença (leia mais sobre isso [aqui](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/33531), [aqui](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/131527), [aqui](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/25585) e [aqui](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_through_obscurity)).

Além disso, vale lembrar que [o SHA1 e o MD5 estão obsoletos há algum tempo](https://it.slashdot.org/story/16/01/08/1427225/deprecation-of-md5-and-sha1----just-in-time) (veja mais sobre isso [aqui](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2014/09/09/sha1-deprecation-what-you-need-to-know), [aqui](https://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2017/02/at-deaths-door-for-years-widely-used-sha1-function-is-now-dead/) e [aqui](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/31871)). Eu sugiro usar algoritmos mais modernos, como os da família [SHA-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2), bastando usar a [função `hash`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) e passando o algoritmo como parâmetro. Exemplos (usando o SHA-256 e o SHA-512):

```
$hash_com_sha256 = hash('sha256', $senha);
$hash_com_sha512 = hash('sha512', $senha);
```

Outra coisa: [Base64 **não** é criptografia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28836880), é apenas um [algoritmo de codificação de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53102/112052), e não muda em nada a segurança (não torna o seu algoritmo mais nem menos seguro). A única coisa que ela faz é aumentar o tamanho original dos dados ([em uma proporção fixa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4715480)), mas como ele é um algoritmo facilmente reversível, não faz diferença nenhuma em termos de segurança.

---

Por fim, recomendo fortemente que leia ["Como fazer hash de senhas de forma segura?"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/2402/112052). E pare de tentar reinventar a roda.

Comment: Complementando e fazendo Jabá do meu próprio post kkkk: [What file size is data if it's 450KB base64 encoded?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34109103/916193)