# Como gerar, codificar e criptografar string aleatória no Flutter

Tags: random, flutter, dart, base64, sha-256

**Preciso gerar um código de 32bytes e codificar para Base64, depois Sha256 e Base64 de novo**

Mas aparentemente esse código tem alguma coisa errada e eu não consigo entender o que é

```
var _random = Random.secure();
var random = List<int>.generate(32, (i) => _random.nextInt(256));
var verificador = base64Url.encode(random);
var base64ToSha256 = utf8.encode(verificador);
var desafio = base64Url.encode(base64ToSha256);
```

Tentei esse:

```
var uuid = Uuid();
var random = uuid.v4();
var verificador = base64Url.encode(random);
var base64ToSha256 = sha256.convert(verificador);
var desafio = base64Url.encode(base64ToSha256);
```

mas aparentemente eu sou muito desprovido de inteligencia e estou fazendo algo muito errado...

Comment: Só um detalhe: base64 [**não** é criptografia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28836880), é apenas um [algoritmo de codificação de dados](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53102/112052). Outro ponto é que fazer `sha256(base64(string))` não trará muito mais vantagens do que fazer simplesmente `sha256(string)`: qualquer combinação maluca dessas [não faz muita diferença](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/400163/112052) em termos de segurança...

Comment: @hkotsubo obrigado pelas informações mas eu realmente preciso fazer desse modo, não estou **inventando minha própria criptografia**, estou apenas fazendo as coisas como me pediram para fazer

Comment: Na verdade eu coloquei o link porque lá tem outros links explicando que não faz diferença fazer essa combinação de base64 com hash com base64 de novo. De qualquer forma, seria interessante explicar para quem pediu que não faz diferença essa primeira conversão para base64 antes de calcular o hash (depois pode fazer sentido dependendo de como vc vai transmitir os dados, embora para hashes seja mais comum representar os bytes como dígitos hexadecimais, mas enfim...)

Comment: @hkotsubo
`codigo_desafio`: [Gerar um 32 bytes aleatórios, converter para hexadecimal, codificar com Base64, substituir os caracteres "+" e "/" por "-" e "_" respectivamente e remover os caracteres "=" para obter o código `verificador` (será utilizado na próxima etapa), com esse código criptografe em SHA256 e codifique com Base64 de forma segura para URL (como fez anteriormente removendo os caracteres)]

Comment: @AristoEinstein Porque acha que possuí algo de errado em seu código? Retorna algum erro? O seu primeiro código, rodei ele e funcionou sem retornar erros.

Comment: @MatheusRibeiro o primeiro código estava errado desculpa.  

Esse é o erro que ele retorna: `The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List<int>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Testei o primeiro código informado por você e funcionou corretamente...

Seguindo os passos do exercício citados em um comentário por você, fiz da seguinte forma

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:math';

void main() {
  var _random = Random.secure();
  var random = List<int>.generate(32, (i) => _random.nextInt(256));
  var verificador = base64Url.encode(random);
  print(verificador);
  verificador = verificador.replaceAll('+', '-')
    .replaceAll('/', '_')
    .replaceAll('=', '');
  print(verificador);
  var base64ToSha256 = utf8.encode(verificador);
  var desafio = base64Url.encode(base64ToSha256);
  print(desafio);
}
```

*Você pode testar neste site do [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/);*

Não ocorreu nenhum erro e foi gerado o resultado esperado.

Veja se não está fazendo nenhum passo errado em seu código.

Comment: Olha a falta de atenção acabando comigo, quando estava usando o base64Url esperava que ele já tirasse os sinais de +, =, e as barras, valeu Matheus.