# De onde vem os nomes "atob" e "btoa"?

Tags: javascript, terminologia, base64

No JavaScript usamos as funções [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/atob) e [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/btoa) para, respectivamente, decodificar e codificar em Base64.

A pergunta é: de onde vem esses nomes?

Comment: Provavelmente inspirado no `atoi` (ASCII to integer) do C, `atob` deve significar ASCII to base64, apesar de que hoje essa função converte UTF-8 para base64, não ASCII.

Comment: Não sei, só sei que são nomes péssimos. `atob` me passa a impressão que é "ASCII to Base64", mas na verdade é o contrário...

Comment: Pois é, eu também fiz umas pesquisas e encontrei isso. Mas realmente é ao contrário... :v

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pesquisando encontrei [esta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33854103). O texto abaixo é uma adaptação de várias respostas que tem lá (e mais alguns adendos meus).

---

[Uma das respostas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50454071) menciona um [*tweet* de Brendan Eich](https://twitter.com/BrendanEich/status/998618208725684224) (considerado o [criador do JavaScript](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich)), que disse que esses nomes vêm de sistemas Unix antigos. Inclusive, o *tweet* dele menciona o [manual de `btoa`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/minix/1/btoa/), no qual temos o seguinte:

```
NAME

       btoa - binary to ascii conversion
```

Ou seja, o `b` significa "binário" e o `a` significa "ascii". Então a ideia de `btoa` ("binary to ascii") é converter de binário para ASCII, e `atob` ("ascii to binary") faz o inverso.

A [especificação do WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#atob) corrobora com essa definição:

> *In these APIs, for mnemonic purposes, the "b" can be considered to stand for "binary", and the "a" for "ASCII". In practice, though, for primarily historical reasons, both the input and output of these functions are Unicode strings.*

Note que, apesar das conversões serem entre "binário" e "ascii", a especificação menciona que na prática as funções do JavaScript recebem e retornam strings (em outras linguagens, como Java, as funções de conversão [retornam arrays de bytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encode-byte:A-), embora possam existir [outros que retornam strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html#encodeToString-byte:A-)).

---

[Outra resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44005295) explica o raciocínio por trás desses nomes, e sua relação com Base64:

Como a [codificação em Base64](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/53102/112052) resulta em uma string na qual [todos os caracteres pertencem a um subconjunto do ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Base64_table), então o `a` ("ascii") representa o texto codificado em Base64. Já o `b` ("binary") indica que aquilo que será convertido para Base 64 pode ser qualquer coisa. E é verdade: no fundo, o algoritmo Base 64 serve para codificar **qualquer sequência de bytes** (não somente texto, mas qualquer outra sequência arbitrária de bytes, sem se importar com o que eles representam).

O que acontece é que - pelo menos no meu caso - eu geralmente uso Base64 com texto, e muitas vezes esqueço que ele também funciona com quaisquer bytes. No caso específico de `atob` e `btoa`, esses nomes sempre me levaram a pensar que o `b` significa "base 64", e eu tenho que lembrar que na verdade é o contrário do que estou pensando. Mas agora que descobri que significa "binary", faz mais sentido...

Mesmo assim, continuo achando que são nomes péssimos. Talvez se fossem `base64Encode` e `base64Decode`, ficaria mais claro o que eles fazem.

Comment: Obrigado por mais uma das suas excelentes respostas! 